# Slickgrid remove CSS when filter is applied

Tags: css, filter, slickgrid

I am using SlickGrid with dataView. I have applied conditional formatting to highlight specific rows when the grid loads with:

```
grid.addCellCssStyles("highlight", rowColor);
grid.invalidate();
dataView.syncGridCellCssStyles(grid, "highlight")
grid.render();
```

When a filter is applied, I would like to remove the css style. I have tried:

```
grid.removeCellCssStyles("highlight");
dataView.syncGridCellCssStyles(grid, "highlight")
```

When the filter is applied, `render()` is called twice. The first time, the style is successfully removed, but the second time `render()` runs it is reapplied. The first time `render()` is called by `onRowCountChanged()`, the secod by `onRowsChanged()`. It appears that on the second render, `updateCellCssStylesOnRenderedRows(addedHash, removedHash)` is using a cached version of the row to reapply the style. An interesting note, the style is cleared for all rows that are hidden by the filter, but the unfiltered rows retain the style. So when I remove the filter, the rows that were hidden have the style removed, but the unfiltered rows are still highlighted.

A side note, I'm a total noob. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Update:** in slick.dataview.js, `syncGridCellCssStyles(grid, key)` , I commented out `storeCellCssStyles(grid.getCellCssStyles(key));` and achieved my desired result. I obviously don't want to edit the source code as my final solution, but hope this will help diagnose the problem. See result below:

> function syncGridCellCssStyles(grid, key) {
>
> ```
>   var hashById;
>   var inHandler;
>
>   // since this method can be called after the cell styles have been set,
>   // get the existing ones right away
>   //storeCellCssStyles(grid.getCellCssStyles(key));
>
>   function storeCellCssStyles(hash) {
>     hashById = {};
>     for (var row in hash) {
>       var id = rows[row][idProperty];
>       hashById[id] = hash[row];
>     }
>   }
>
>   grid.onCellCssStylesChanged.subscribe(function(e, args) {
>     if (inHandler) { return; }
>     if (key != args.key) { return; }
>     if (args.hash) {
>       storeCellCssStyles(args.hash);
>     }
>   });
>
>   this.onRowsChanged.subscribe(function(e, args) {
>     if (hashById) {
>       inHandler = true;
>       ensureRowsByIdCache();
>       var newHash = {};
>       for (var id in hashById) {
>         var row = rowsById[id];
>         if (row != undefined) {
>           newHash[row] = hashById[id];
>         }
>       }
>       grid.setCellCssStyles(key, newHash);
>       inHandler = false;
>     }
>   });
> }
> ```

Comment: `grid.invalidate` calls `render` internally - so you are calling render twice when applying the styles. Also, have you tried invalidate when you remove styles as well?

Comment: Gotcha... I'll correct that. The render() called twice I'm talking about is called when I update the grid to apply the filter. I've tried invalidate, refresh, render, a combination therof. I've gotten to the point where I feel like I'm just throwing darts in the dark without an understanding of how it is working. I do think the row cache storing the css style might be the problem but I don't know why it isn't updating for unfiltered rows.